# IntelliJ is too smart for me

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I'd like to implement simple jpa named queries with IntelliJ IDEA using final Strings to defined parameters. But the inspector do't like it and told me 'unexpected token' to the ':' on the end of the first part of the query. How can I suppress the inspection or how can I convince the inspection to accept that.

```
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = TaxonEntity.selectBytaxonId,
  query = "SELECT t FROM TaxonEntity t WHERE t.taxonId  =:" + TaxonEntity.TAXON_ID)
})
@Entity
public class TaxonEntity {

static public final String selectBytaxonId = "TaxonEntity.selectBytaxonId";
static public final String TAXON_ID = "taxonId";
....
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Medrod

UPDATE:
The IntelliJ IDEA will accept the query if after the constant a String will be appended.

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = TaxonEntity.selectBytaxonId,
query = "SELECT t FROM TaxonEntity t WHERE t.taxonId =:"+TaxonEntity.TAXON_ID+"")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = TaxonEntity.selectBytaxonId,
  query = "SELECT t FROM TaxonEntity t WHERE t.taxonId = " + TaxonEntity.TAXON_ID)
})
@Entity
public class TaxonEntity {
    static public final String selectBytaxonId = ":TaxonEntity.selectBytaxonId";
```

Alternatively you may just want to make the whole query a constant. It'd be a bit more readable.

Comment: I always found it curious when people use symbolic constants for local identifiers. It's the whole constants thing taken a bit too far.

Comment: I can understand the rationale (I used to do this myself a lot) but now I don't think it's worth the readability. I rather have strings just used inline in the annotations and rely on good unit tests to let me know if/when someone breaks something in the future.

Comment: That makes no sense. The idea behind this implementation is to declare at one site a name for a property and use it in the declaration of namedQuery and later to create the query and to commit parameters to the query.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, create a second constant which includes the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

What SQL database are you using?

As I remember the equal operator in SQL is `=` not `=:`.

The IDEA inspector complaining is probably not java inspector, but SQL inspector. IDEA is quite smart and knows what is what.

Comment: The : is a part of JPA Query language. With =:paramerterName you can later use the paramerterName to add specific parameter to the namedQuery.